# Roll-your-own JMX corporate solution or find another way to control config, logging, etc on live apps?

Tags: java, jmx, dashboard

Because JMX seems so widely available on publicly available Java libraries, I was surprised that authentication and authorization were barely implemented and impossible to use in production docker environments.

Because the basic RMI implementation doesn't work in a firewalled, load-managed, dockerized prod environment, I worked out how to implement JMX via the JMXMP protocol but I'd have to implement large parts of the authentication and authorization myself on the server and the client.

How else could I use JMX? What other platforms or libraries are there to control logging output levels, connection pools, memory monitoring etc?